# How to parse JSON response from an API url using https request in java?

Tags: java, json, file, text, httpurlconnection

how to parse the JSON response from an api url using java? When I run the below code
I am getting SocketTimeoutException. but when browse the URL in the Chrome and Microsoft Edge i am getting the JSON data.

url:"https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE"
(use only for testing purpose. not for commercial use)

**Java Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class HTTP_Request {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        Send_HTTP_Request.call_me();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    
    public static void call_me() throws Exception {
    
        String url ="https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        
        //print in String
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        
        //Read JSON response and print
       // JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
       // System.out.println("result after Reading JSON Response");
       // System.out.println("origin- "+myResponse.getString("origin"));
         
        }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using HttpUrlConnection use HttpsUrlConnection as your API call is running on https.

Comment: I tried using httpsUrlConnection but I am still getting Read Time out error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look what happens when you call the provided url from a shell curl:

```
> $ curl 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE'                                                 [±master ●●▴]
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;nseindia&#46;com&#47;api&#47;quote&#45;derivative&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;15b5655f&#46;1595338785&#46;264b3809
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

So, I guess nseindia is blocking the request because is not coming from a browser.
But, if you try this:

```
curl 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: ak_bmsc=D709927FAB6A44F1C243E20E9199ABA35F65B5158B040000E1EF165F44B95756~plIifDJa9J1EHznQiR/zQpjmGEFWOE88N83Yuqa0oOcgvvYh7eLlgD5MSFVhCZZOObVMZ7UDwEzmOQ2V2lJ6W9pPf6zEbQT1Je27i6h3hrAIyBYFMplV1EDo7rSLxXmCk+HGL3ynHmuPJsePDPD7WTljjTMnM1qpvixsCMEtM1BlmVmuXQijd8cKjWxLeLaf/cNAEJB6VC7SXOq+j6uj6oi9xF/Z2NYB905XnUg9YppXM=' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'
```

you get a json in the response.

```
{"info":{"symbol":"RELIANCE","companyName":"Reliance Industries Limited",.......}
```

So you need to add a couple of HTTP Headers to your request, something like:

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
```

Comment: Glad it works! @DeepakMukundancan you please accept the answer? thanks